# paws::dynamodb query() returns attributes with all their possible value types

Tags: r, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using operation **query** from function **dynamodb** from library **paws.database** in R.

When I run the query:

```
  response = svc$query(
  ExpressionAttributeValues = list(
    `:v1` = list(
      S = "request-grant-generation"
    )
  ),
  TableName = table_name,
  KeyConditionExpression = "dumpType = :v1"
)
```

This returns a list of 5. The data is in the **Items** element.

Every record has 8 Attributes. Every attribute returns all the possible data types, and with data **only** in the correct one.
Here's an example with the first record in Items and the first attribute (version).

```
> response$Items[[1]]$version
$S
[1] "1"

$N
character(0)

$B
character(0)

$SS
list()

$NS
list()

$BS
list()

$M
list()

$L
list()

$`NULL`
logical(0)

$BOOL
logical(0)
```

Is there a way to tell the **paws.database** or **dynamodb** not to return all the possible types but the one in the db? Because otherwise I will need to parse the response and drop al the non-applicable value types and keep the one that has values in it.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution parsing the list.

Using **rlist** library made it extremely easy to solve.
The doc is [here](https://renkun-ken.github.io/rlist-tutorial/index.html)

The line of code to solve the shown example would be:

```
library("rlist")
list.clean(response, function(x) length(x) == 0L, recursive = TRUE))
```

Hope someone find it usefull.

> My db has no empty records. If you have a db with empty attributes that need to be preserved, you should modify the comparison in the function or refer to a more specialized one.

This is the way to go to a clean dataframe:

```
# Flatten DynamoDB query response, which has only attribute names and values.
flatten <- function(x) {
 result <- list() for (name in names(x)) {
 result[[name]] <- get_value(x[[name]]) 
} 
return(result) 
} 

get_value <- function(x) {
 element <- names(x)[sapply(x, function(el) length(el) > 0)] if (is_empty(element)) return("") return(x[[element]]) 
}
```

Comment: Wow, after hunting so many places, this is amazing. I'm curious how I could go from this cleaned list to a data frame? The scan contains the `Items` list, but each now has a format like `response$Items$varName$varType: value`. Curious if this was your next step as well?

Comment: Used this:

# Flatten DynamoDB query response, which has only attribute names and values. 
flatten <- function(x) {
  result <- list()
  for (name in names(x)) {
    result[[name]] <- get_value(x[[name]])
  }
  return(result)
}

get_value <- function(x) {
  element <- names(x)[sapply(x, function(el) length(el) > 0)]
  if (is_empty(element)) return("")
  return(x[[element]])
}

Hope this was you meant. Sorry about the delay. Never noticed the flag in my inbox

Comment: Please update your post instead of putting so much code in a comment. It's hard to read.